# Debugging deployment of a war file

Tags: java, tomcat, war

I was given WAR file to deploy on the tomcat server. I have installed tomcat6 on Amazon linux.

So, I simply dropped the WAR in the directory `/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/` and then restarted tomcat.

When I hit the url, I simply get a 404 NOT found as the following:

[image]

I checked the log file in `/var/log/tomcat6/catalina.out` and there is no error message in there. What is the correct way to debug this issue? If there are any errors in the WAR file, where can I check those errors?

Comment: Perhaps you need to append context to url. If your war was `foo.war`, then you can try a url that looks like `http://host:port/foo`.

Comment: yes. I  hit the complete url `http://host:port/foo/something`, it doesn't work. I can see the folder `foo` created in the webapps directory. Where can I find the error logs?

Comment: Couple of things to try. Do you see a message in catalina.out which tells application started fine. Something like: Deployment of web application archive /some/path/foo.war has finished in 100 ms. Second, if you have admin access to tomcat, you can verify if your app is deployed by logging-in into tomcat manager.